# Spring boot + Big Query using wrong project id

Tags: spring-boot, google-bigquery, spring-cloud

So I'm a little bit new to big query and gcp in general.

I'm trying to send data to big query, and when it does, it's pulling my production credentials when it should be using my dev credentials.

application-local.yml

```yaml
    spring:
      config:
        name: local
      jpa:
        show-sql: true
        generate-ddl: true
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      datasource:
        platform: postgres
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
        username: username
        password: TestPass
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      profiles:
        active: local
      application:
        name: user-api
      cloud:
        gcp:
          bigquery:
            dataset-name: app-dev
            project-id: app-dev
            credentials:
              location: classpath:google-dev.json
          sql:
            enabled: false
          credentials:
            encoded-key: [b64 credentials]
          project-id: app-dev
          config:
            project-id: app-dev
```

starting logs showing it picking up the dev project

```java
    2021-05-05 14:09:23.683  INFO 37046 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is app-dev
    2021-05-05 14:09:23.707  INFO 37046 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for service account server-dev@app.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    2021-05-05 14:09:23.707  INFO 37046 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
```

When it actually tries to run big query inserts

```
    2021-05-05 14:09:27.900 ERROR 37046 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Not found: Dataset app-prod:app-dev
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.insertAll(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:494)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.insertAll(BigQueryImpl.java:1036)
        at ca.app.api.domain.repository.datalake.DataLakeInterface$DefaultImpls.save(DataLakeInterface.kt:27)
        at ca.app.api.domain.repository.datalake.CycleEventDataLakeRepository.save(CycleEventDataLakeRepository.kt:12)
        at ca.app.api.tasks.DataLakeSyncTasks.syncCycleEvents(DataLakeSyncTasks.kt:99)
        at ca.app.api.tasks.DataLakeSyncTasks.syncDataLake(DataLakeSyncTasks.kt:71)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
    POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/app-prod/datasets/app-dev/tables/cycle_event_table/insertAll?prettyPrint=false
    {
      "code" : 404,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Not found: Dataset app-prod:app-dev",
        "reason" : "notFound"
      } ],
      "message" : "Not found: Dataset app-prod:app-dev",
      "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
    }
```

I have no clue where it's picking up app-prod. The only place app-prod is used is application-prod.yml which only has the prod profile. The auth file and the base64 key all only contain app-dev.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is solved, but I was facing the same.

Probable causes:

1. logged in using `gcloud auth application-default login` from SDK.
2. using this way to initialize

   BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

This will take SDK configurations. Solution is to just autowire BigQuery like

```
@Autowired
BigQuery bq;
```

Answer (score 0):

is it perhaps inside the key file google-dev.json?

Comment: nope. google-dev.json is a poorly named file that actually is used for firebase. I use firebase auth for authenticating requests. But that references a firebase dev project, so not even gcp.